# KeyPairGenerator RSA512 signing error on JWT

Tags: java, jwt, key-pair

Autogenerated RSA (512bit) keypair gives key length error while signing or parsing Claims. when i try to use 1024bit RSA code is working, but still JWT configured as RS512.
When i try to check token on [jwt debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) it gives **invalid signature**.

i generated 1024bit RSA, how RS512 is working with 1024bit RSA?

**codes are as follows:**

```java
public JwtUtil() throws Exception {
       KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
       kpg.initialize(512);
       KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

       System.out.println(kp.getPrivate());
       System.out.println("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");
       System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
       System.out.println("------END PRIVATE KEY------");
       System.out.println("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
       System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPublic().getEncoded()));
       System.out.println("------END PUBLIC KEY------");

       secret_key = kp.getPrivate();
}
```

**keypair output:**

```
SunRsaSign RSA private CRT key, 512 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 7601809965540561359509816601988074293551191141989978875146926955998131556140998184761208135689250313813989553710817084679571823318927874570265090788702603
  private exponent: 1189620565582556377361378748950816942409036366514323562926390937344047442510036558397360889583782021886617860703448643224975214481114339798954443100484737
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAkSTfg/fwSSMMFfGOh76yOBGgX9LrcevnQpWNrt5/CDRsYSKTg/tSzCbqEAZLSMV1LousZd/7gPfHtCmtWww5iwIDAQABAkAWtr6D2Hkx+NobVQIJHD6np5qBZHCUE2bNdLoHc6pNjimLwZKR45KQv8BIrymijPNo6MPTGrydilujTVg6ZXSBAiEApDL4gzbMNS6jHe0OKVdnOGwCWylPqdzzx46wXCKDcVcCIQDiSqRQg77HpD8UNo1w+f1wiFKvMWrI2PVk2PgH8RqU7QIgXQogtMEFHxFpDhj30EcdTuQsxZj38ekoHShmGB7aWgsCIDtHcmPlH0UNMbkJ0WOXGV0xWPer6l1S+HXCoLbz4hLBAiEAjjJv/Mpo3J/RAvvkikXJX3WDgeGCILklnvM/MZ38V3A=
------END PRIVATE KEY------
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJEk34P38EkjDBXxjoe+sjgRoF/S63Hr50KVja7efwg0bGEik4P7Uswm6hAGS0jFdS6LrGXf+4D3x7QprVsMOYsCAwEAAQ==
------END PUBLIC KEY------
```

**signing function:**

```java
private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
       return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject)
              .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
              .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * expire_duration_sec))
              .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS512, secret_key)
              .compact();
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too short for this signature algorithm
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.initCommon(RSASignature.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineInitSign(RSASignature.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineInitSign(RSASignature.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.tryOperation(Signature.java:1318) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1272) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1356) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.RsaSigner.doSign(RsaSigner.java:54) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.RsaSigner.sign(RsaSigner.java:43) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSigner.sign(DefaultJwtSigner.java:45) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:322) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at pw.cicek.jcms.core.auth.token.JwtUtil.createToken(JwtUtil.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344559/key-is-too-short-for-this-signature-algorithm-while-signing might be relevant

Comment: JOSE/JWS/JWT algorithm **`RS512` is NOT 512-bit RSA** which is very easily broken, it is RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using _SHA-512 as the hash_. An RSA key must be much larger than a symmetric key for the same security, and if you really need the 256-bit security level of SHA-512, your RSA key must be about 15k bits; see https://www.keylength.com . [Example A.2 in JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.html#appendix-A.2) shows  RS256 (SHA-256) using 2048-bit RSA, although 3072 is recommended for this level.